# Extract the name of the movie or TV serie

Tags: php, extract

What is the best solution to extract the name of the movie or TV serie from this path; `E:\Dropbox\Hemsidor\collection-test\movies\avatar\documents\actors.txt`?

I have checked `explode` but that solution are just annoying if you have to split every `/` from the path.

**EDIT**

The search can result in more than one hits. The results can be displayed as this:

```
E:\Dropbox\Hemsidor\collection-test\movies\avatar\documents\actors.txt
E:\Dropbox\Hemsidor\collection-test\movies\the_butterfly_effect\documents\actors.txt
```

How can I loop the titles?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need Regex for this simple search. In fact RegEx is slower for large scale data. 
Following code will do it perfectly

```
$string = 'E:\Dropbox\Hemsidor\collection-test\movies\avatar\documents\actors.txt?';
$a = explode('\\', $string);
echo $a[array_search('movies', $a)+1];
```

Comment: That solution was also very simple, if not simpler :P Many thanks!

Comment: Well, RegEx is slower for large scale data.

Comment: That's very true. But how can I extract more than one title with your solution? I forgot to mention that in my question *ashamed* I don't know how to explain it as good as possible but if some actor is in more than one title, more paths will show up.

Comment: @ErikEdgren for multiple string use it in loops.

Comment: Thanks :) I got it to work. I'll accept your solution because it's faster than RegEx.

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = 'E:\Dropbox\Hemsidor\collection-test\movies\avatar\documents\actors.txt?';

preg_match('/\\\movies\\\([^\x5C]+)/', $string, $matchs);

echo $matchs[1];
```

Comment: That did the trick! Many thanks for a very simple solution :) I'll accept it when I can.